# Plotly Dash Graph With Multiple Dropdown Inputs Not Working

Tags: python-3.x, plotly-dash

I’m trying to create a time-series Dash line graph that has multiple interactive dropdown user input variables. I would ideally like each of the dropdown inputs to allow for multiple selections.

While I’m able to create the drop down menus successfully, the chart isn’t updating like I’d like. When I allow the dropdowns to have multiple selections, I get an error that arrays are different lengths. And when I limit the dropdowns to one selection, I get an error that [‘Vendor_Name’] is not in index. So this may be two separate problems.

Graph that doesn’t work:

[image]

Snippet of Excel data imported into DF

[image]

```
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd
#import plotly.graph_objs as go 
df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv", sep = "\t")
df['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YearMonth'], format = '%Y-%m')
cols = ['Product_1', 'Product_2', 'Product_3']
vendor = df['Vendor'].unique()

app = dash.Dash('Data')

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([

            html.Label('Product'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                 id = 'product',
                 options = [{
                         'label' : i, 
                         'value' : i
                 } for i in cols],
                multi = True,
                value = 'Product_1'

                 ),
                ]),

        html.Div([

            html.Label('Vendor'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
             id = 'vendor',
             options = [{
                     'label' : i, 
                     'value' : i
             } for i in vendor],
            multi = True,
             value = 'ABC')
             ,
        ]),
            ]),

    dcc.Graph(id = 'feature-graphic')
    ])


@app.callback(Output('feature-graphic', 'figure'),
    [Input('product', 'value'),
     Input('vendor', 'value')])


def update_graph(input_vendor, input_column):


    df_filtered = df[df['Vendor'] == input_vendor]

##also tried setting an index because of the error I was getting. Not sure if necessary
    df_filtered = df_filtered.set_index(['Vendor']) 

    traces = []

    df_by_col = df_filtered[[input_column, 'YearMonth']]

    traces.append({

        'x' :pd.Series(df_by_col['YearMonth']),
        'y' : df_by_col[input_column],
        'mode' : 'lines',
        'type' : 'scatter',
        'name' :'XYZ'}
        )

    fig = {
                    'data': traces,
                    'layout': {'title': 'Title of Chart'}
                    }
    return fig


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=False)
```

Thanks in advance for helping! Still new-ish to Python, but very excited about Dash’s capabilities. I’ve been able to create other graphs with single inputs, and have read through documentation.

Answer (score 3):

Here is the approach I followed: (editing common example available in google with my approach):

```
import dash
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html

app = dash.Dash(__name__)

all_options = {
    'America': ['New York City', 'San Francisco', 'Cincinnati'],
    'Canada': [u'Montréal', 'Toronto', 'Ottawa']
}
app.layout = html.Div([
    dcc.Dropdown(
        id='countries-dropdown',
        options=[{'label': k, 'value': k} for k in all_options.keys()],
        value='America',  #default value to show
        multi=True,
        searchable=False
    ),

    dcc.Dropdown(id='cities-dropdown', multi=True, searchable=False, placeholder="Select a city"),

    html.Div(id='display-selected-values')
])

@app.callback(
    dash.dependencies.Output('cities-dropdown', 'options'),
    [dash.dependencies.Input('countries-dropdown', 'value')])
def set_cities_options(selected_country):
    if type(selected_country) == 'str':
        return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for i in all_options[selected_country]]
    else:
        return [{'label': i, 'value': i} for country in selected_country for i in all_options[country]]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)
```

**Workaround here is:** When there is single input present in parent dropdown, the value is in string format. But for multiple values, it comes in list format.
This code also work perfectly and gets updated automatically even when you click on cross option to remove any selected option.

**Note:** I have used 'placeholder' attribute instead of defining default value for it as it made no sense in this case. But you can also update the value dynamically in similar way.

Answer (score 2):

#### 1 input data

The data as it is in the `csv` is hard to loop.
And I would argue that it is the main reason your code does not work,
because you seem to understand the fundamental code structure.
Having put on my SQL glasses I think you should try to get it to sth like

```
Date, Vendor, ProductName, Value
```

#### 2 callback input types change

`multi` is tricky because it changes switches between returning a `str` if only 1 item is selected and `list` if more than one is selected

#### 3 callback return type

you code returns a `dict` but the callback declared `figure` as the return type

but here is the code with debugging traces of `print()` and `sleep()`

```
import pandas as pd
import dash
import dash_core_components as dcc
import dash_html_components as html
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import plotly.graph_objs as go
import time

df = pd.read_csv("Data.csv", sep="\t")
df['YearMonth'] = pd.to_datetime(df['YearMonth'], format='%Y-%m')
products = ['Product_1', 'Product_2', 'Product_3']
vendors = df['Vendor'].unique()

app = dash.Dash('Data')

app.layout = html.Div([
    html.Div([
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Product'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='product',
                options=[{'label' : p, 'value' : p} for p in products],
                multi=True,
                value='Product_1'
            ),
        ]),
        html.Div([
            html.Label('Vendor'),
            dcc.Dropdown(
                id='vendor',
                options=[{'label': v, 'value': v} for v in vendors],
                multi=True,
                value='ABC'
            ),
        ]),
    ]),
    dcc.Graph(id='feature-graphic', figure=go.Figure())
])


@app.callback(
    Output('feature-graphic', 'figure'),
    [Input('product', 'value'),
     Input('vendor', 'value')])
def update_graph(input_product, input_vendor):
    # df_filtered[['Product_1', 'YearMonth']]
    if type(input_product) == str:
        input_product = [input_product]
    if type(input_vendor) == str:
        input_vendor= [input_vendor]

    datasets = ['']
    i = 1
    for vendor in input_vendor:
        df_filtered = df[df['Vendor'] == vendor]
        for product in input_product:
            datasets.append((df_filtered[['YearMonth', 'Vendor', product]]).copy())
            datasets[i]['ProductName'] = product
            datasets[i].rename(columns={product: 'Value'}, inplace=True)
            i += 1
    datasets.pop(0)
    print(datasets)

    traces = ['']
    for dataset in datasets:
        print(dataset)
        time.sleep(1)
        traces.append(
            go.Scatter({
                'x': dataset['YearMonth'],
                'y': dataset['Value'],
                'mode': 'lines',
                'name': f"Vendor: {dataset['Vendor'].iloc[0]} Product: {dataset['ProductName'].iloc[0]}"
        }))
    traces.pop(0)
    layout = {'title': 'Title of Chart'}

    fig = {'data': traces, 'layout': go.Layout(layout)}
    return go.Figure(fig)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server()
```

#### quick and dirty disclosure:

If you handle the **1. issue** it will dramatically simplify everything.
So I'd try to isolate the `pd.DataFrame()` juggling out of the callback and into the upper I/O part.

1) don't use counters in for loops

2) my variable names aren't the best either

3) the following style is caveman's python and `there must be a better way`:

```
traces = ['']
traces.append(this_and_that)
traces.pop(0)
```

#### Generally:

using `print(input_variable)` and `print(type(input_variable))`
gets my wheels most of the time out of the mud.

#### after all

you should notice that each `trace` got its  individual name which will show up in the legend. Clicking on the name in the legend will add or remove the `trace` without the need for`@app.callback()`